# Probability of Someone Winning a Dice Game

Tags: probability

How do I calculate the probability **someone** will win a game from the perspective of the house?

Say I run a casino with 1 game: dice rolling. Any player who rolls the same number as I do on a single dice is a "winner". Winners will split the prize evenly.

The 1 player case is easy. The probability a player will roll a given number is 1/6, so the probability *someone* will win is 1/6.

I get more confused when thinking about 2+ players. For 2 players, is the probability someone will win now 1/3 adding 1/6 and 1/6 for each player together? Is the probability *someone* will win for 6 players 100% or is it some other formula?

Comment: What probability would you compute for *seven* players?  Then, returning to the two player case, can you work out the chance that *nobody* will win?  Generalize that to more players.

Comment: It feels like it should be like 80 or 90%? I can't say why.

Comment: As whuber suggests, compute the probability that *nobody* wins.  That should be straightforward application of the product rule.

Comment: Ah ok googling the product rule was helpful! The probability no one wins with 1 player is 5/6 or 83%%, for 2 players it's 5/6 * 5/6 = 76%. By the time you reach 50 players it's <1%.